# How to sum item in transaction subdocument mongodb from other document relationship

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

I'm new in mongodb and try small project and document are design just like below

*products*

```json
[
    {
      _id:ObjectId('60d87d6fafd7a1377c03b2e6'),
      productName:"noodles instant",
      description:"lorem ipsum ... ... ...."
    },
    {
      _id:ObjectId('60d87d6fafd7a1377c03b2e7'),
      productName:"Sandal",
      description:"lorem ipsum ... ... ...."
    }
]
```

and my transaction document has structure is just like below
*transactions*

```json
   [
    { 
       _id:ObjectId('60d8781031308dbf565eaaa8'),
       trasactionSerial:"TRS20210000001",
       transactionDate:2021-06-27T13:30:23.369+00:00,
       productInTransactions:[
          {
            _id:ObjectId('60d8781031308dbf565eaab9'),
            productId:ObjectId('60d87d6fafd7a1377c03b2e6'),
            qty:1500
          },
          {
            _id:ObjectId('60d8781031308dbf565eaa47'),
            productId:ObjectId('60d87d6fafd7a1377c03b2e7'),
            qty:200
          }
          
       ]
    },
    { 
       _id:ObjectId('60d8781031308dbf565eaab7'),
       trasactionSerial:"TRS20210000002",
       transactionDate:2021-06-27T13:32:23.369+00:00,
       productInTransactions:[
          {
            _id:ObjectId('60d8781031308dbf565eaab9'),
            productId:ObjectId('60d87d6fafd7a1377c03b2e6'),
            qty:100
          },
          {
            _id:ObjectId('60d8781031308dbf565eaa47'),
            productId:ObjectId('60d87d6fafd7a1377c03b2e7'),
            qty:300
          }
          
       ]
    }   
   ]
```

from the transaction I hope will get some result like below from the same date in `transactionDate`  field

*result*

```json
   [
     {
       _id:ObjectId('60d87d6fafd7a1377c03b2e6'),
       productName:"noodles instant",
       qtyInTransaction:1600
     },
     {
       _id:ObjectId('60d87d6fafd7a1377c03b2e7'),  
       productName:"Sandal",
       qtyInTransaction:500
     },
   ]
```

> sorry maybe my English  is poor to elaborate it

thanks for any feedback and your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$lookup` stage which has `$group` in its pipeline option.

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "transactions",
      "let": {
        "pId": "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$unwind": "$productInTransactions"
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$productInTransactions.productId",
                "$$pId"
              ]
            },
          },
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$$pId",
            "qtyInTransaction": {
              "$sum": "$productInTransactions.qty"
            }
          },
        },  
      ],
      "as": "matchedTransactions"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "description": 1,
      "qtyInTransaction": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$matchedTransactions.qtyInTransaction",
          0
        ]
      }
    },
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/laNPraZDGUr)

Comment: hi , thanks bro you save my day as beginner